# Resize cursors in Microsoft Edge are not shown when parent container has Content Editable enabled

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I am using interactjs to add a resize functionality on the images added in the Kendo WYSIWYG Editor. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Microsoft Edge it won't show the resize cursor though the resize functionality works. Has anyone else encountered these issues too?

**UPDATE:**

Found out that `contenteditable` makes the cursor for Edge not work but I need the parent to be `contenteditable` since it is a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. Solve the issue by adding a parent container with `contenteditable="false"`.

Changing the template to have this fixed the issue.